# TypeError: inner() got multiple values for keyword argument 'ax'

Tags: matplotlib

I tried to run the below code:

Code:

```
df1=pd.read_excel('F:/MRCS_New_struture/2. EHM_Vanna/2015 Reports/Statistic_Env.xlsx', sheetname='Daitom (2)', header=0, index_col='Year')


CaAB=df1.iloc[:5,17:34]; print CaAB

a=[2007, 2008, 2011, 2013, 2015]
b=[100,200,300,500,22.33]

fig, ax=plt.subplots(2,1)

plt.plot(a, b, 'go-', label='line 1', linewidth=2, ax=ax)
plt.xticks(a, map(str,a))
CaAB.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax)
```

And, it generated error (TypeError: inner() got multiple values for keyword argument 'ax'). What's wrong to my code?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`ax` is not a valid argument for `plt.plot()`. The reason is that `plt.plot()` will call the `plot` method of the current active axes, same as `plt.gca().plot()`. Hence the axes is already given by the instance itself. Supplying it again as keyword argument does not make any sense and eventually produces the error.

Solution: Don't use `ax` as argument to `plt.plot()`. Instead,

1. call `plt.plot(...)` to plot to the current axes. Set the current axes with [`plt.sca()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.sca), or
2. directly call the `plot()` method of the axes. `ax.plot(...)`

Mind that in the example from the question, `ax` is not an axes. If this is confusing, name it differently,

```
fig, ax_arr = plt.subplots(2,1)

ax_arr[0].plot(a, b, 'go-', label='line 1', linewidth=2)
ax_arr[0].set_xticks(a)
ax_arr[0].set_xticklabels(list(map(str,a)))

df.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax_arr[1])
```